# How to append new entry in child pyrebase

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pyrebase

the Below code replaces the previous entry but i want to add new entry or append the new entry in the child name Friends_email please if any one can help me. I am using python 3.9 with Pyrebase 3.0.27.

```
li = {"1":"gurjar"}
db.child("Users").child("nishant").child("Friend_list").child("Friends_email").set(li)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes previously I was writing.

```
li = {"1":"gurjar"}
db.child("Users").child("nishant").child("Friend_list").child("Friends_email").set(li)
```

But now I am using

```
db.child("Users").child("nishant").child("Friend_list").child("Friends_email").child(1).set(“gurjar”)
```

Now if I will change child 1 to 2 then it will append it in the child Friends_email.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `set` overwrites the existing data at the path with the new data you specified. If you want to add a new child under the path with the new data, use `push`. If you want to merge the new data with the existing data at the path, use `update`.

Also see the Pyrebase documentation on [push](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#push) and [update](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#update).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but push creates a new child it does not append the value in another child and update changes the whole value I just want to append new data in previous child only don’t want to create a new child.

Comment: I think at this point it is safe to say that I don't understand what you want. Please edit your question to show the JSON you have under `Friends_email` and what you want it to be be after the code runs.

Comment: Thanks for your time but i solved it myself

Comment: Good to hear. Can you post your solution as an answer, so others can benefit from it too?